# AVPlayer paused in Corona Plugin

Tags: ios, coronasdk, avplayer

I make native iOS Corona plugin. I have `AVPlayer` in my code. When I show view controller with video, player begins play and then automatically stop. I tried to catch call `pause` method, but no one breakpoint doesn't work. In log console before pause I see

`2017-03-21 17:40:00.210068 AdsTestApp[1218:1053525] Metal GPU Frame Capture Enabled
2017-03-21 17:40:00.211245 AdsTestApp[1218:1053525] Metal API Validation Enabled`

What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that for some reasons ViewController deallocated. Now question is WHY?